# Scope date until date+week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want get all my records which have a `start_date`(So not the normal creation_date) from my stringed date(11-20-2013) within a scope of 1 week.

I've never really used scoping in Rails before so I'm rather lost here. Should I use a .where()? If so, How do I adress start_date+1 week in this scope?

I've tried something like:

```
  if params[:startdate]
    group = Group.find_by_id(params[:group_id]).where(:start_date => params[:startdate]..params[:startdate] + 1.weeks)
  end
```

Which throws: `can't convert ActiveSupport::Duration into String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `params[:startdate]` is String when you need DateTime.

You can try to parse it

```
startdate = DateTime.parse(params[:startdate]) rescue nil
if startdate
  group = Group.find_by_id(params[:group_id]).where(:start_date => startdate..startdate + 1.weeks)
else
  # you get wrong startdate
end
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm getting a `undefined method where' for #<Group:0x8623338>`

Comment: Is `Group` a model (class `ActiveRecord::Base`)?

Comment: Fixed it; Turned it around. Thanks!